# Can implement Offline mode for Forge viewer svf2?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm investing that can we implement offline mode for svf2 forge viewer.

Currently, I'm using svf format and downloading all requests by urn which I got in the manifest.json file. It works by the cache size is quite large.

Now I try to use svf2, and it's performance is better, but I'm not sure if we can implement offline mode for it. I read in document that `Additionally, in the manifest, SVF2 derivatives do not have a URN. This means that SVF2 derivatives cannot be downloaded for offline viewing.` (ref: https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/basics/preperation/).

Anybody knows about this or have implemented this function?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Offline usage on SVF2 is not supported so far. Please use SVF if you want to donwload translated viewer files.